# Feasibility of product idea

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, product-engineering

I have an idea for a sports equipment innovation "a new product" that a track and field athlete can use to practice and train his sport. The technology involves a laser beam. I'm wondering if my idea is feasible and/or if it has already been done because we think the idea is good.

The idea is that when training pole vault or height jump, the athlete uses a laser beam instead of a bar, and the laser beam measures if the athlete succeeds. Has it already been done or is it not feasible?

Comment: Hi Programmer 400, welcome to Engineering SE. Our site is specifically targeted at solving practical problems rather than brainstorming or discussing ideas. for more information, see [this help center article](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) or search our [meta] site. This question doesn't meet our standards for the main site, but it would be fine to ask in [chat].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's certainly feasible.  I don't know if it has been done.  I don't think it's a great idea, for the following reasons:

1) What would the athlete be aiming for?  It won't be as visible.

2) In the actual sports, you're allowed to touch the bar, as long as it doesn't fall.

3)  You may be affected (put-off) by the presence of a physical bar in a competition, when you trained without one.

It would potentially shorten the time between attempts, but it would be less representative of the real thing.